# Why my code is slow when printing crystal report, also not printing on desired printer?

Tags: vb.net, printing, crystal-reports

I am programming a retail sales system that should print on 4 types of printers, Receipt, A4, A5, and Label.
my problem is that I need to print the receipt without changing the default printer however I can print normally if the printer is set to default.

What makes me wonder is I already set the name of the desired printer but it prints to the default one and in any case it takes 6-10 seconds which is not acceptable in such software, here is my code:

```
Private Sub PrintFromDS()
    Dim rptDoc As New ReportDocument
    rptDoc = New CRrcpt
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim doctoprint As New System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument()
    doctoprint.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = RcptPrinter
    Dim rawKind As Integer
    For i = 0 To doctoprint.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Count - 1
        If doctoprint.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes(i).PaperName = "72mm x Receipt" Then
            rawKind = CInt(doctoprint.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes(i).GetType().GetField("kind", Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(doctoprint.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes(i)))
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds)
    rptDoc.PrintOptions.PaperSize = CType(rawKind, CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSize)
    rptDoc.PrintToPrinter(1, False, 0, 0)
    rptDoc.Refresh()
    End If
End Sub
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any issues with your code.

The **For** loop is the only place where you could have slowed down the code.

But my speculation is that it really takes a long time for the printer to wake up. It also depends on the Printer Driver. Some printers respond different to different frameworks.

My experience is that if you put a loading element, such as a animation, or continues progressbar, that the user does not feel 6 seconds anymore.

If you put a Messagebox("test") at the end of the code. does does the message box come up immidiately? if so, it means your code runs well, but the printer does not. It might mean that the data source itself is not optmized, or that your printer is weakly powered.

Comment: I changed the printer to xps writer it took the same time also I tested the printer in several ways and nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Regarding the For Loop, I just have 2 printers and microsoft xps writer so it is not a big deal, another thing Why the code prints to default printer while the code already gave the desired printer name? Strange

Comment: I think it's a crystal report issue, to be more specific, I use CR 13.0.24.2970 and VS2010 Ultimate SP1, the report reads from dataset..! any suggestions?

Comment: I am still looking for a somthing but I could not find any solution, someone experienced please suggest me something.!